# All chart values do not show in line graph in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

Iam creating a line graph with 2 lines. Everything is displayed properly except when i use `renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true)` the values are plotted but not all titles of the values are displayed.

Can anybody help me with this?
Thank you

Here is the code

```
renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer1.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDC143C"));
        renderer1.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer1.setFillPoints(true);
        rRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);

        renderer2= new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
         renderer2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6B8E23"));
        renderer2.setFillPoints(true);
        rRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the minimum distance between chart values in order to get more of them displayed. For instance:

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(10);
```