# TimeChart with XYMultipleSeriesRenderer has lines with missing values

Tags: android, achartengine

I inherited some code that uses a TimeChart along with XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to create a multiple-series LineChart. Example shown below.

[image]

There are 2 major problems with the above chart:
1) The series in blue does not show a label for any of the 4 data points
2) Some of the data points (i.e. 2441.474 and 2388.316) are too close to each other.

At the very least, I would like to find a solution for #1.  Below is the code snippet that I'm using to generate the view.

**Create XYMultipleSeriesDataset:**

```
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset createLineDataset() {
    List<String> titles = mData.getColumnHeadings();
    List<List<Double>> values = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
    List<Date> actualDays = new ArrayList<Date>();

    // Add the dates that we have data for
    for (String heading : mData.getRowHeadings()) {
        long toAdd = DateUtil.getLongFromDateStringFromMachineMeasurement(heading);
        actualDays.add( new Date(toAdd) );
    }
    for (JdTableColumn column : mData.getColumns()) {
        List<Double> columnBodyAsDoubles = column.getColumnBodyAsDoubles();
        Log.d(TAG, "Column doubles: " + columnBodyAsDoubles.toString());
        values.add(columnBodyAsDoubles);
    }

    return buildDataset(titles, values, actualDays);
}

  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildDataset(final List<String> titles, final List<List<Double>> values, final List<Date> dates) {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    int length = titles.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(titles.get(i));
        List<Double> valueList = values.get(i);
        int seriesLength = valueList.size();

        for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
            series.add(dates.get(k), valueList.get(k));
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series);
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

**Create Time Chart:**

```
GraphRange range = getStandardGraphRange();
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(mData.getColumnHeadings().size(), PointStyle.POINT, true, context, range.getMin(), range.getMax());
TimeChart timeChart = new TimeChart(createLineDataset(), renderer);
    timeChart.setDateFormat(TIME_CHART_DATE_FORMAT);
    GraphicalView chart = new GraphicalView(context, timeChart);
```

The only Stackoverflow question that somehow resemble the issue I'm seeing is: [All chart values do not show in line graph in achartengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032462/all-chart-values-do-not-show-in-line-graph-in-achartengine). However, in that post they were using XYSeriesRenderer and the renderer I'm using (XYMultipleSeriesRenderer) does not have the suggested method setDisplayChartValuesDistance().  If anyone has a suggestion on how to fix the issue I'll appreciate your feedback.

**Update:**
As per the accepted answer, I had to use setDisplayChartDistance() method on each XYSeriesRenderer that gets added to the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer:

```
for (XYSeriesRenderer r : createBarSeriesRenderers(seriesLength, pointStyle, displayChartValues, context)) {
        r.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(8);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the minimum distance in pixels between two consecutive labels. Based on this value, the chart knows if and when the chart value labels need to be displayed.

```
mRenderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(distanceInPixels);
```

Comment: That method doesn't seem available for XYMultipleSeriesRenderer. Or at least for the version of AChart I'm using. Was this added recently?

Comment: It is in XYSeriesRenderer.

Comment: I have a pre-compiled jar file (we inherited this code so not sure what version) and Android Studio does not recognize the suggested method. I check in the docs for XYMultipleSeriesRenderer (http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html) as well as its super class (http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.html) and I don't see that method.

Comment: Try the latest: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/

Comment: I downloaded the jar file from your link (achartengine-1.2.0.jar)and the suggested method is still unavailable. I did noticed, however, that some methods got deprecated/removed (i.e. setDisplayChartValues(true) for SimpleSeriesRenderer). The new version of the library changed how the pie chart looks (numbers are inside the chart as opposed to line connecting to number outside the chart) so it looks like I'll have to stay with our current AChart version for now. However, I would like to confirm that your suggestion indeed works so that I can at least mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: As I said above, the method is in XYSeriesRenderer. An instance of XYSeriesRenderer is one element inside an XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.

Comment: The suggested method didn't work for me in the old version of the library. With the new library I could see the missing data labels with/without the method which probably means the default value for distance got reduced. Thanks.